# In Python 3.x, why does os.chdir() behave differently when used with os.listdir() and os.scandir() ? (Python 3.9.7)

Tags: python

I am puzzled by the behavior of `os.chdir()` when called on items generated by `os.listdir()` versus items generated by `os.scandir()`. I realize that `os.scandir()` creates `DirEntry` objects, whereas `os.listdir()` does not (maybe just returning strings), but if that explains the behavior I'm seeing, I still don't quite get *why*. Here's what I mean:

I have a directory with three subdirectories. I want to get into each subdirectory, do something, then go into the next one and do the same thing, etc. For pedagogical purposes, I'm not using `os.walk` or anything else sophisticated. Here's the code that shows the confusing (to me) result (note that this is just test code, so I'm doing the simplest possible "thing" here, i.e., printing something):

```
def listdir_test(path="D:/python-venvs/pyinst"):
    print("\n----- listdir() output ---------")
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isdir(item):
            print(item)
            os.chdir(item) # this happens only once, for the first directory found
            print(os.getcwd())

def scandir_test(path="D:/python-venvs/pyinst"):
    print("\n-------- scandir() output ------------")
    for item in os.scandir(path):
        if os.path.isdir(item):
            print(item)
            os.chdir(item) # this happens three times, for each of the directories found
            print(os.getcwd())

listdir_test()
scandir_test()
```

As you can see, these functions are identical except that one operates on `listdir()` output, and the other operates on `scandir()` output. But the first function gives up after only one `os.chdir(item)` operation, rather than doing it for all three directories. The second function behaves as I expect, repeating the `os.chdir(item)` operation for each of three directories. Here is the output of the above code:

```
----- listdir() output ---------
1.3.1.2-modules
D:\python-venvs\pyinst\1.3.1.2-modules

-------- scandir() output ------------
<DirEntry '1.3.1.2-modules'>
D:\python-venvs\pyinst\1.3.1.2-modules
<DirEntry 'packages'>
D:\python-venvs\pyinst\packages
<DirEntry 'pyinst-venv'>
D:\python-venvs\pyinst\pyinst-venv
```

I do not understand why `os.chdir(item)` apparently causes the `for` loop to bail out when I'm using it with `os.listdir()` output. There's probably a good reason. For learning purposes, I'd love to know what it is, so I can better understand these functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When treated as a path (by functions like `os.chdir`), a `DirEntry` object is converted to its `path` attribute, not just a bare name. In contrast, `os.listdir` returns bare names.

In your `os.listdir` code, you're passing bare names around, which are treated as relative to the current working directory. Once you *change* the current working directory with `os.chdir`, these names no longer resolve to what you wanted them to resolve to.

In contrast, your `os.scandir` code uses file paths, and since the original `scandir` argument was an absolute path, the paths you get out of `scandir` are absolute too. The interpretation of an absolute path doesn't depend on the current working directory, so stuff doesn't break when you change the working directory.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I guess I hadn't thought it through enough. I can see now how the relative path generated by `listdir()` wouldn't work once I'm inside a new subdirectory. I was thinking that returning to the top of the for loop would put me back where I started, but obviously if all the `for` loop gave me was a relative path, then that's not right. Thanks for helping me learn something!